# Format method of Decimalformat returns numeric instead zero

Tags: java, format, decimalformat

I am using `DecimalFormat's` format method to format float value with 6 decimal points.  So I am using,

```
Float f = new Float("52.2815");
DecimalFormat decfo = new DecimalFormat("#0.000000");
String k = decfo.format(f);
```

I want to print `52.281500`. But it prints `52.281502`. How to get `52.281500`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because floating points don't have enough bits and hence your output data is soured. You can use a Double.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Double f = new Double("52.2815");
        DecimalFormat decfo = new DecimalFormat("#.000000");
        String k = decfo.format(f);
        System.out.println(k);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
52.281500
```